# how to open .xml file using Intent in application?

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application, I want to open all types of files using Intent. I tried to open files like .pdf, .text, .image, .gif, .mp3, .mp4, word file, .html.

Those are open correctly. But I don't know how to open .xml file .

Comment: It is unlikely that the user has a text editor app installed, with which to view XML files.

Answer (score 0):

it might work for you please try

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:scheme="file"  android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.xml"  android:mimeType="*/*"  />
</intent-filter>
```